# Function execution continues after return in catch block

Tags: javascript, async-await

Using async / await, I tried two different syntaxes :

```js
async function asyncFunc() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
         reject('promise rejected')
        }, 500);
    });
}

async function asyncCallWithoutTryCatchBlock() {
    await asyncFunc().catch((err) => {
   console.log('Catching error');
        return;
    });
    console.log('Outside, after catch is called');
}

async function asyncCallWithTryCatchBlock() {
  try {
   await asyncFunc();
  } catch(err) {
   console.log('Catching error');
   return;
  }
  console.log('Outside, after catch is called');
}

asyncCallWithoutTryCatchBlock();
asyncCallWithTryCatchBlock();
```

**I am expecting this output :**

```
Catching error
Catching error
```

**I get this :**

```
Catching error
Outside, after catch is called
Catching error
```

I am wondering why is the outside `console.log` is called in the `asyncCallWithoutTryCatchBlock` as I am doing an explicit return in the `catch` block ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return is inside the anonymous function that you pass to the catch method. As such, it only returns from that anonymous function. Being the last statement in the function, it actually serves no purpose at all.

The big difference between the two code snippets is that one uses the language construct try catch and the other is using a method called catch which expects an anonymous function.